# How to register the volt engine without using the dependency injector?

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I want to render a volt file using Phalcon view. How can I register the volt engine without the dependency injector?

Comment: I am getting this error : "A dependency injector container is required to obtain the application services"

Answer (score 0):

Follow the manual to use Volt as [stand-alone component:](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.4/volt#stand-alone)